# With sudo, is it possible to execute a program using a target group which the target user is not in?

Tags: sudo, group

Please consider a Linux system with a standard installation and configuration of `sudo`; that is, `root` can execute all commands, taking the identity of other users, and please consider the following command:

```
sudo -u user1 -g group1 some_program
```

Of course, I would expect that `some_program` gets executed with EUID `user1` **and** with EGID `group1`. However, I have learned the very hard way that this works only if `user1` is actually a member of `group1`; I really should have studied `man sudo` more thoroughly. From the explanation of the `-g` command line option:

> [...] The sudoers policy permits any of the target user's groups to be specified via the -g option as long as the -P option is not in use.

This is very inconvenient. I often use `sudo` for testing purposes, especially when a service or program runs under arbitrary UIDs and GIDs, the respective user not being a member of the respective group. In such cases, before I can test with `sudo`, I have to make the respective user a member of the respective group and must not forget to revert that action when the tests are finished.

Hence the question: Is there a setting or configuration which allows `root` to `sudo`-execute programs using arbitrary UIDs and GIDs *which do not match*? I am only interested in solutions which provide a general mechanism for *all programs, UIDs and GIDs*. That is, putting lists of specific programs, UIDs or GIDs into `/etc/sudoers` is not an option.

One possible solution could be an alternative policy provider for `sudo` which would allow for that. However, learning how to install and configure it would probably be very hard, and I'm unsure about whether I'd take that route, even if there was no other solution. Furthermore, I haven't found such a thing so far.

**UPDATE 1 (2022-01-27)**

The system in question runs Debian buster, updated with all available patches at the time of writing this. SELinux is *not* installed. This is my `/etc/sudoers` file (leaving out *only* comments and empty lines):

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
ipupdate ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /root/scripts/asterisk-external-ip
```

I currently believe that the last line does not have anything to do with the problem and that I probably should have removed it to minimize distraction. On the other hand, I have learned that sometimes it's just the seemingly unimportant "removed for clarity" parts which actually cause the respective error.

Comment: Provided your starting account is in the `sudo` group, then you should be able to pick any account _name_ from `/etc/passwd` and/or any group _name_ from `/etc/group` and have it work. (Except for `ipupdate`, of course.) For example on my system, `sudo -u bind -g incron id` gives me `uid=111(bind) gid=123(incron) groups=123(incron),116(bind)`

Comment: Indeed, it's not the `ipupdate` command I'm testing :-) I have a program which runs under a certain UID and GID (started by a systemd unit) and which can't read read a certain file although it should, according to file and directory permissions. Now I am trying to debug the problem by executing `sudo -u <user> -g <group> <program>`, but then the program can't read the file either. The respective group has read and write permissions for the file, so either sudo doesn't execute the program as expected, or something else goes wrong; perhaps that program drops rights somehow (yet to investigate).

Comment: Remember you can also go interactive on this, `sudo -u bind -g incron bash` (or whatever). You can then dig around to try and identify why your program can't access the file

Comment: Thank you! That's a very good idea which will make life easier. I'll for sure try that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Executing a program in a different target group is the whole point of the `-g` option. And there's no restriction on combining `-u` with `-g`.

> The sudoers policy permits any of the target user's groups to be specified via the -g option as long as the -P option is not in use.

It's not explained clearly, but what this sentence is referring to is what sudo lets you do out of the box, which is not the point of using sudo. Sudo is useful with *additional* policies in the `sudoers` file, and these can allow arbitrary sets of users and groups.

Root doesn't get any special permissions. If you can run `sudo -u user1` as root or as a “sudoer” user, it's because there's a rule in the sudoers file that allows it. For some reason (maybe because the maintainer just never thought of updating it), in the sample `sudoers` file, this rule is

```
root        ALL = (ALL) ALL
%wheel      ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

This only allows the use of `sudo -u`, not of `sudo -g`, except the limited use of `-g` to specify the primary group among the groups that the user already one. To allow elevating group privileges as well as user privileges, change these rules (or whatever the equivalent on your system is, e.g. with `%admin` or `%sudo` or `binarus` etc.) to

```
root        ALL = (ALL:ALL) ALL
%wheel      ALL = (ALL:ALL) ALL
```

This is the default on some distributions, for example Debian.

Comment: Please excuse the late reply. Thank you very much for the answer, much appreciated and +1. But unfortunately, I already had the correct entries in `/etc/sudoers` (that is, the entries with `(ALL:ALL)`); this is a Debian buster system where I didn't touch the `sudoers` file yet. I'll add that file to my question in a few minutes.

Comment: OK, thanks again. Your answer is correct and accepted. I don't know what's going on with that specific program I was testing, though. Regardless of whether I'm starting it with `sudo` with the correct credentials or not, it can't read that specific file. But this should be made a matter of a separate question ...

Comment: @Binarus Is the program a bash script, or are you invoking it via a bash wrapper, by any chance? Bash drops privileges by default. Most other shells (e.g. dash) don't.

Comment: The program in question is `procmail`. I am executing it directly (without a wrapper). The situation is complicated because `procmail` is installed SETUID root and SETGID mail, but seems to drop those privileges at some point when executing, returning back to the privileges of the user / group invoking it, which should be the user and group which I gave `sudo` at the command line by `-u` and `-g`. It's the `-g` part which gives me (understanding) problems. I'll have to investigate this later due to time constraints, but knowing at least that sudo `-g` works as expected is a good basis.

Comment: Oh, well, if the program is doing its own group management, that's a completely different problem. Sudo gives it the extra group you want, but then the program voluntarily removes it. Running `sudo -g group1 sg group1 procmail …` might work. Or maybe you need to drop all the other groups.